# Manual sign in with devise writes to session but user doesn't get carried onto next request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I am trying to do a custom sign in in a controller and while the session gets filled with warden data, on the next request the data isn't there anymore.

I have this (simplified for debugging) action in my controller:

```
def login
  p "current user was", current_user
  p session
  user = User.find(467)
  sign_in(:user, user)
  p "current user is", current_user
  p session
end
```

Then I hit the action from browser and each time I get the same result with user not being present in the beginning, after sign in its set and on next request the user is nil again.

```
"current user was"
nil

{"session_id"=>"810ea69e6be089976dbcf663fc34b08b", "_csrf_token"=>"aKuBz/wi8zInUYkW/kgsSLVvsksql2TBJzYVhaJfY+8="}

{"session_id"=>"810ea69e6be089976dbcf663fc34b08b", "_csrf_token"=>"aKuBz/wi8zInUYkW/kgsSLVvsksql2TBJzYVhaJfY+8=", "warden.user.user.key"=>[[467], "$2a$10$skME2XEHLBnz3/xYXQerrO"]}

"current user is"
#<ContentPartner id: 467, name: >

{"session_id"=>"810ea69e6be089976dbcf663fc34b08b", "_csrf_token"=>"aKuBz/wi8zInUYkW/kgsSLVvsksql2TBJzYVhaJfY+8=", "warden.user.user.key"=>[[467], "$2a$10$skME2XEHLBnz3/xYXQerrO"]}
```

Any tips on how to debug, what to check?

Comment: after sign in what user will do, they will redirect to other page? Check if you have destroyed session in somewhere, or try using helper `sign_in_and_redirect`

Comment: I saw some people had issues with redirect so I removed it to make sure it doesn't break the signup. The code is complete, nothing else is run and the user is just not signed in afterwards :(

Comment: if you use default sign in function of devise, does it works?

Comment: yep the default way works, I need a different sign in for another part of the app though.